# BarButtonItem of a ViewController not in a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I have a view controller that I set directly as the rootViewController in my window.

However in my view controller when I type

```
self.navigationItem
```

I notice that it is not nil. Shouldn't it be nil given that it is not embedded within a UINavigationController. What would explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

All instances of `UIViewController` have a read-only property, `navigationItem` of class `UINavigationItem`. `UINavigationItem`, isn’t necessarily an item in itself, but rather a way to configure the item(s) that a `UINavigationController` (or some other view controller) may use.

So while the `navigationItem` property may not be nil, its values for `title`, `prompt`, `titleView`, `leftBarButtonItems`, `rightBarButtonItems`, etc. are likely to be `nil` by default.

---

Note that while `UINavigationController` is the most common consumer of the `navigationItem` property in its active view controller, it is not necessarily the only thing that can use the `navigationItem` property. You could create your own custom view controller container to use this property of its child view controllers to display a custom representation of the `navigationItem`.